# Getting the current time without a script task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a project parameter that sets the max amount of time it can run. I set the User::StopTime variable to DATEADD("mi", User::MaxRun, System::StartTime). Now, in the loop that reads a block of rows, I want to keep getting a block at a time until I'm out of rows or now is past User::StopTime. I see System var that give me the container start time, but what I need is the time now. Is there a way to get that without a script? Not a big deal, just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [GETDATE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139875.aspx). That should get re-evaluated each time it's inspected vs a static value like `@[System::StartTime]`

I created a simple package with a Variable `CurrentTime` of type DateTime and set an Expression on it of `GetDate()`

[image]

I put a For Loop Container on there to count from 0 to 1000 and then inside that put a Script Task that simply printed the value of `@[User::CurrentTime]` to prove that yes, it's evaluated at every inspection and then ran it.

Comment: So setting a var to GETDATE() will give me the current datetime each time the variable is referenced?

Comment: Thanks again! SSIS debugging still confounds me.

Comment: Hello Downvoter ([@TheOptimusPrimus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2517150/theoptimusprimus)) I see that you've voted this as "not useful". Could you help me understand what is lacking so that I may improve the answer?

Comment: That's just too pathetic.